# why do some access points hide SSID and some don't?

Tags: networking

I was wondering why do some access points show their SSID "Service Set Identifier" while others do not?

Thank you

Comment: Not an electronics design question - better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

Because its ***optional*** and not everyone wants or needs to broadcast their AP's SSID.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old security tip that has long been discredited, but people still keep bringing up.  The theory is that you should turn off the SSID broadcast so people randomly scanning won't see the broadcast and therefore won't know you have a WAP.  Security through obscurity.  The problem is that doesn't truly work.

Comment: It stops the casual user.

Comment: @cde it doesn't really.  A casual user won't get through a system with any kind of password or passphrase.  A dedicated user won't be significantly hindered by it.

Comment: @davidgo you think hiding the ssid doesn't somewhat hinder the casual user from attempting to log on, or even ask about logging on to a wifi ap?

Comment: Of-course it somewhat hinders the casual user.   You think that a password does not stop the casual user ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of bad, stupid information.

With SSID broadcast on the AP broadcasts an identity every now and them. Compare it to a person shouting (hey. Here I am. My name is X).

With it turned off that does not happen. But people communicating with the AP still broadcast its ID in plain text though the ether (Think of it as john NOT broadcasting his availability.  Mike enter the room and shouts "Hi John, I got some data for you".

Effectively nothing is hidden.

Worse, it makes it easier to put a fake AP in the same area, making things less easy to use and less secure. Still, the old myth that you should turn it of somehow perseveres.